# read a file just written don't have the same data with Ionic4 file plugin

Tags: angular, file, ionic4, exif

i work in angular / ionic 4 and i use the file plugin to write in a file.
The goal is to open a picture, change EXIF and save the picture.

I change the EXIF and i use the code as below to save my file

here is my code :

```
              this.file.writeExistingFile(rep, fic, insert).then(
                (data) => {
                  this.file.readAsBinaryString(rep, fic).then(
                    (data2) => {
                      console.log('data2', data2);
                   });
                }
              );
```

i try to save data as follow (insert variable)
[image]

and when i read the file, i have this data in the picture and of course the picture don't display like it is corrupted.
[image]

Did i miss something when i saved my file?

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a solution.

In fact the file reader of ionic add type:base64, at the beginnig if the file, i deleted it and convert my data in Arraybuffer and all goes good

```
const base64ToArrayBuffer = base64 => {
  const binaryString = window.atob(base64);
  const len = binaryString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

 const dataBlob = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64.split(',')[1]);

  return file.writeFile(rep, fic, dataBlob, { replace: true, append: false }).then(() => {
    return true;
  });
```

And it finally works ^^